# CRM Dynamics workflow not triggering for all records

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, crm

Problem: Set up a workflow in CRM Dynamics 365 Sales that starts when the value of a specific field changes. But it turned out that the process does not start if changes are made to old CRM records (which were created before starting the process itself).

Question: Is there any method how can I make CRM start the process even for old records? I am sorry that everything is in Russian. I work in this version.
The process works correctly when creating a record and when editing a field in a new record. And when editing a field in an existing record, the process does not start

[image]
[image]

Comment: Some misunderstanding. WF should trigger irrespective of record created after WF creation or before.

Comment: The process works correctly when creating a record and when editing a field in a new record. And when editing a field in an existing record, the process does not start. I don't understand, is this a bug or a feature of the system?

Comment: whats the scope of WF? Org or user or BU ? It should be Org then it will work

Comment: Now I have a user specified

Comment: change it to Org. It will work

Comment: Try Organization

Comment: Super! It turned out to be easier than I thought)) And in what cases do you need to specify the user?

Comment: pls see my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that Workflow to trigger on all records, make the scope as “Organization” instead of “User” - it should work as intended. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipstricksnewstomaster/posts/4-workflow-scopes-in-microsoft-dynamics-365-crm-and-how-to-set-them-up)

It’s not about when it is created, probably those records are owned by somebody else. That’s why user scoped WF is not triggering at all.

Answer (score 0):

Normally workflows trigger any future relevant changes. Otherwise, we should create a scenario where we cause that trigger. A couple of options,

1. As you have already set the workflow to run on a specific field change, you can make an update to that field and save the record which should trigger the workflow. If it's a very less number of records it's possible otherwise it's not a good idea to manually update all these records. If you don't want to do this manually you can update the records using any other option like a console app which makes updates to all the records (this would be faster assuming this is a one-time activity you have to do.)
2. Make this workflow on demand and trigger the same manually for all the records you want to run the workflow. Again this is a manual process but cleaner than the first one.

Comment: Unfortunately, the process does not start. This field is specified in the process settings as a trigger. The process should also start when new records are created. In this case, it works and starts. What could be the problem?(

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any manual update. The workflow you creates should be enough to kick in.
make sure your workflow has trigger on change of field. Screenshot for reference. It does not matter when the Workflow is created. As long as it satisfies condition it will kick in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the process does not start. This field is specified in the process settings as a trigger. The process should also start when new records are created. In this case, it works and starts. What could be the problem?(

Comment: so you say your process starts when record is created but not when field is chaged?
could you add screenshot to your question from your worklow? What is the trigger, what is the filed been selected and so on so that we can narrow it down

Comment: I supplemented my question and added screenshots. thanks

Comment: Perhaps, in the scope field, instead of the user, specify the Organization?

Comment: Yes I think Arun mentioned it the same. Try changing it to Org and if it helps marks this answer as solved and upvote too :)

Comment: How do I mark two comments as a solution? There is only one I can choose

Comment: yes no worries you can still upvote answer suggested.